# Wave Equation - Initial Value Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given
$$ u_{tt}−\Deltau = 0, \ \  for \ \ t≥ 0, \ x∈ \mathbb{R^3} $$ 
With initial conditions
$$ u(x, 0) = cos|x| $$ 
$$ u_t(x, 0) = 1 $$
Find $u(0, t)$ for all times $t>0$ 
$$$$
Perhaps here it is possible to somehow use D'Alambert's formula by reducing the system to radial coordinates using $r$ instead of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Use Kirchhoff Formula